# Implementing nrf51822 timer example mbed

Tags: embedded, mbed, nrf51822

I am using the PCA10001 eval board and I have been able to get things up and running using the mbed platform but now I am implementing a timer based interrupt for that I was using a ticker. But detaching and reattaching the ticker results in the ticker not working properly. My time for calling the interrupt is 1ms.

Facing issues with the ticker I want to use the nrf51 timer1 or 2. I ran the example code here https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/nrf51-TIMER-examples/blob/master/timer_example_timer_mode/main.c

with a few modifications

```
#include "mbed.h"

DigitalOut myled(LED1);
RawSerial pc(USBTX, USBRX);

void start_timer(void)
{       
  NRF_TIMER2->MODE = TIMER_MODE_MODE_Timer;  // Set the timer in Counter Mode
  NRF_TIMER2->TASKS_CLEAR = 1;               // clear the task first to be usable for later
    NRF_TIMER2->PRESCALER = 6;                             //Set prescaler. Higher number gives slower timer. Prescaler = 0 gives 16MHz timer
    NRF_TIMER2->BITMODE = TIMER_BITMODE_BITMODE_16Bit;       //Set counter to 16 bit resolution
    NRF_TIMER2->CC[0] = 25000;                             //Set value for TIMER2 compare register 0
    NRF_TIMER2->CC[1] = 5;                                 //Set value for TIMER2 compare register 1

  // Enable interrupt on Timer 2, both for CC[0] and CC[1] compare match events
    NRF_TIMER2->INTENSET = (TIMER_INTENSET_COMPARE0_Enabled << TIMER_INTENSET_COMPARE0_Pos) | (TIMER_INTENSET_COMPARE1_Enabled << TIMER_INTENSET_COMPARE1_Pos);


  NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIMER2_IRQn);

  NRF_TIMER2->TASKS_START = 1;               // Start TIMER2
}

/** TIMTER2 peripheral interrupt handler. This interrupt handler is called whenever there it a TIMER2 interrupt
 */
void TIMER2_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if ((NRF_TIMER2->EVENTS_COMPARE[0] != 0) && ((NRF_TIMER2->INTENSET & TIMER_INTENSET_COMPARE0_Msk) != 0))
  {
        NRF_TIMER2->EVENTS_COMPARE[0] = 0;           //Clear compare register 0 event   
        myled=1;         //Set LED
  }

    if ((NRF_TIMER2->EVENTS_COMPARE[1] != 0) && ((NRF_TIMER2->INTENSET & TIMER_INTENSET_COMPARE1_Msk) != 0))
  {
        NRF_TIMER2->EVENTS_COMPARE[1] = 0;           //Clear compare register 1 event
        myled=0;      //Clear LED
  }
}

int main(void)
{
      pc.baud(9600);

    start_timer();                              //Configure and start timer

    while(true) 
    {
//              pc.printf("%i\n",1);

//         Enter System ON sleep mode
        __WFE();
        // Make sure any pending events are cleared
        __SEV();
        __WFE();

//         For more information on the WFE - SEV - WFE sequence, please refer to the following Devzone article:
         //https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/index.php/how-do-you-put-the-nrf51822-chip-to-sleep#reply-1589
    }
}
```

It compiles with no errors but nothing happens. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong.

I have tried using both updated and old mbed libraries.

Comment: I have a feeling that the SoftDevice may conflict with the mbed use of the timer hardware. Did you search the mbed site for ideas?

Comment: Yes, I have posted the same question there as well waiting to hear from them. Meanwhile I ran the same code using Keil uVision and preloaded the softdevice using NRFgo studio and it works fine but not when compiling with mbed.